# найти период максимальной нагрузки

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

В БД хранится время входа и выхода пользователей в формате datetime. Для определения максимальной нагрузки нужно для определенных суток найти промежуток времени, в течении которого в системе находилось максимальное количество пользователей.

Comment: Какая бд? Что конкретно вы пытались сделать и что у вас не получилось ?

Comment: Если вы про субд - mysql. Не могу понять, как вычислить тот момент, когда залогинено максимальное количество пользователей.

Comment: Какой продолжительности промежуток имеется в виду - секунда, минута, час? Зная, что Вы взяли за минимальный промежуток, легко вычистить нагрузку...

Comment: Промежуток не фиксированный. Например, в 12:10 залогинился пользователь - их стало 100 - максимальное количество залогиненых за день; в 15:00 кто-то вышел - стало 99. Значит искомый промежуток с 12:10 до 15:00.

Comment: сделайте запрос, отсортировав записи по времени события. после этого в цикле пройдите по записям, при «входе» увеличивайте значение счётчика на 1, при «выходе» — уменьшайте на 1. фиксируйте в отдельных переменных максимальное значение счётчика, время, когда счётчик достиг этого значения, и время, когда он его «потерял».

Comment: кстати, таких периодов ведь может быть и несколько. так что придётся заводить не просто переменные для фиксации времени, а массив таких переменных.

Comment: @woland попробуй потестить на большом объеме данных скрипт, я набросал: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8b003/1/0
max_in - начало периода, min_out - конец периода, u_online - кол-во юзеров онлайн

Comment: @namak7, спасибо за скрипт. Я решил на php - получилось быстрее.